# Prevent default (showing file dialog) on form file input in Bootstrap-Vue

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to override the default file browser dialog with a custom function when the user clicks on the file selection dialog as shown below in Bootstrap-Vue.

The code is

```
<b-form-file
  v-on:click.prevent
  v-model="file"
  :state="Boolean(file)"
  placeholder="Choose a file or drop it here..."
  drop-placeholder="Drop file here..."
></b-form-file>
```

I tried adding `v-on:click.prevent`, and `@click="function (e) {e.preventdefault()}"` but those don't work for me.

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-file/

[image]

Comment: try `v-on:click.native.prevent`, since `<b-form-file>` is a component, you need to tell it to listen to a native browser event.

Comment: And since b-form-file is inside a `<div>` wrapper, you may want to add on the `.capture` modifier to trap the event before it reaches the input

Comment: @TroyMorehouse thank you, that works to suppress the dialog. How can I now trigger a custom function on click (e.g. `alert("hello world")`)? I tried adding `@click='alert("hello world")'` but I'm only able to get that to work when added to a div wrapped around the <b-form-file> tag

Comment: try `v-on:click.native.prevent="alert('Hello World'}"`

Comment: @TroyMorehouse, yes that solves my problem! Thank you sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to prevent the default file browser from showing (and to run your own action on click) would be something similar to the following:

```html
<b-form-file @click.native.prevent="alert('Hello world')"></b-form-file>
```